# deleting certain lines in ms word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]I would like to delete certain lines from my word document using a VBA macro. Basically the (block of) text to be deleted (and replaced by "***") follows a certain pattern (below).

```
Bottom of Form
perma-link

Top of Form
save
Bottom of Form
[+] ....
[–] ....
Top of Form
```

"...." represents text that changes every block, but for sure the line starts with "[+]" or "[-]".

Please suggest a suitable macro

EDIT: In the screenshot, I would like to keep the text in yellow and delete the rest. (in the actual file, the text isn't in yellow)

PS-FYI, I tried using the example [looping a find and delete row macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398227/looping-a-find-and-delete-row-macro) (for line by line deletion) but i get a runtime error 5941 with debugging option highlighting the line "selection.row.delete" in the macro.

What does this mean?

Comment: `selection.row.delete` would work only for tables which you don't have, I think. I don't get the pattern you tried to present- what should be replace. Could you add some screen shots or more details?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Kasjow. Ok, let me pose a simpler question, how to individually delete lines that start with a particular string?

Comment: by lines you mean paragraphs? so, each line is a paragraph...

Comment: @KazJaw, in a sense yes. The lines that I would like to delete are not in paragraphs but are separate lines in the document in fact (they appear regularly between paragraphs, individually)

Comment: So, please check it- are there paragraph marks at the and of these lines? if not, what kind of line separation marks there are?

Comment: @KazJaw, no paragraph marks but the spacing of these lines is greater than the spacing within paragraphs. Hence these are separate.

Comment: Go to MS Word, press Ctrl+* to show all document symbols and add a screen shot to your question. You need to define ending point of your 'lines'. If they are not paragraphs then you will have problems as there is nothing like 'line object' in MS Word.

Comment: I can't see special document symbols. See my answer and attached screen shot for what I mean.

Comment: I see, so it means the paragraph symbol is necessary for my solution. Thanks KozJow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the example list is a list of paragraphs beginnings the following code should do the trick. What you have to do is to place all 'paragraphs starting' into array `arrRemove` as I did for the test. If any of the mark is a special marks (see [this link for additional information](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)) you need to add `\` in front of it as I did for `[+]` and `[-]`. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim arrRemove As Variant
        arrRemove = Array("Bottom of Form", "perma -link", "Top of Form", _
                    "\[+\]", "\[\-\]", "Donec", "In")

    Dim i!
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrRemove)
        Activedocument.Range(0,0).select

        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = arrRemove(i) & "*^13"
            .Replacement.Text = ""  'replace with nothing

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Next i

End Sub
```

The above macro will remove all yellow paragraph in the following document.

[image]

Comment: I have added a screenshot for your convenience